# Error During installing this library " pip install bcrypt" in django

Tags: python, django, pip, django-3.0

I got an error while installing bcrypt in Django

> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in
>   C:\Users\Hassan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-w128k6kc\cffi\
>
> ```
>   ----------------------------------------
> Command "C:\Users\Hassan\PycharmProjects\django_level_5\venv\Scripts\python.exe
> ```
>
> C:\Users\Hassan\PycharmProjects\django_level_5\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py
>       3.8.egg\pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix C:\Users\Hassan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-ky7v9nxx\overlay
>   --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :
>       none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools>=40.8.0 wheel "cffi>=1.1; python_implementation != 'PyPy'""
>   failed with error code 1 in None

Comment: check this: https://github.com/pyca/bcrypt/issues/58

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply these three commands

```
pip uninstall  bcrypt cffi pycparser
pip install --user --upgrade cffi
pip install --user --upgrade bcrypt
```

if this error is show

> microsoft visual c++ 14.0 is required

then you have to download **vs_buildtools** after installing and
enter these above commmands again